# Как создавать войс-каналы в одной категории? | Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Надо создавать войс-каналы в одной категории. Пытался использовать следующий метод:

```
guild = client.get_guild(тут айди сервера)
create = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"custom voice", category=тут айди категории)
```

Но выдает ошибку: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'`

Также пробовал вариант `create.edit(category=тут айди категории)`

Выдает такую же ошибку, как и выше.

Попробовал следующий вариант:

```
category = await ctx.guild.create_category("custom", overwrites=None, reason=None)
create = await category.create_voice_channel(f"custom voice", overwrites=None, reason=None)
```

Но при каждом выполнении команды, как не странно, оно создает новую категорию с войс-каналом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось проще, чем я думал.

`category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name = "Tickets")`

Нашел на гитхабе в тикет-боте.
https://github.com/Sk1pzz/Discord-Ticket-System/blob/main/cogs/event.py (62 строка)